# Python-pptx - How to delete all shapes in pptx slide in python?

Tags: python, powerpoint, shapes, python-pptx

I use this library : https://python-pptx.readthedocs.io/, and I'm looking for a method to delete all shapes of a slide (and to replace by shapes taken from another slide).
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible, though it is a little tricky. I adapted the code from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64700638/is-there-a-way-to-delete-a-shape-with-python-pptx) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50866634/python-pptx-copy-slide).

```
from pptx import Presentation
import copy

prs = Presentation("test169_presentation.pptx")
def delete_shapes(prs, slide_index):
    for shape in prs.slides[slide_index].shapes:
        shape_element = shape.element
        shape_element.getparent().remove(shape_element)

def copy_shapes(prs, source_slide_index, dest_slide_index):
    source_slide = prs.slides[source_slide_index]
    dest_slide = prs.slides[dest_slide_index]
    unused_shape_id = max(shape.shape_id for slide in prs.slides for shape in slide.shapes) + 1
    for shape in source_slide.shapes:
        new_shape = copy.deepcopy(shape.element)
        dest_slide.shapes._spTree.insert_element_before(new_shape, 'p:extLst')
        
delete_shapes(prs, 1)
copy_shapes(prs, 0, 1)

prs.save("test169_presentation2.pptx")
```

This program is deleting the shapes from slide 2, then copying the shapes from slide 1 to slide 2.

Before:

[image: two different slides]

After:

[image: the same slide twice]

Comment: Ok, thanks, it doesn't work for images and hyperlinks but I found a solution for that. Thanks a lot your code helped me a lot!